# How to get Id by ajax

Tags: html, ajax, html-table

I have a table that is contain of `Id, user, pass`. I want to have `id` by clicking on the button.
My code is :

```
function LoadData(data) {  
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
            var datea = '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + item.id + '</td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" value=" ' + item.usser + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" value="' + item.pass + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input id="Up" type="button" name="btnUpdate" value="Update" /> ' +
                     '<input type="button" name="btnDelete" id="' + item.id + '" onclick="test();" value="Delete" /></td>' +
            '</tr>';
            $('#customerTable').append(datea);
        });
    };

function test() {
        var customerId = $(this).parent().parent().children().get(0).innerHTML;alert(customerId);
        var data = '{"id":"' + customerId + '"}';    
}
```

By load data my db files shows on the html page. Function `test` is for get id of row.

Comment: What issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
function LoadData(data) {

$.each(data, function (key, item) {
    var datea = '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + item.id + '</td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" value=" ' + item.usser + '"/></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" value="' + item.pass + '"/></td>' +
        '<td><input id="Up" type="button" name="btnUpdate" value="Update" /> ' +
             '<input type="button" name="btnDelete" id="' + item.id + '" onClick="test(\'' + item.id  + '\')"  value="Delete" /></td>' +
    '</tr>';
    $('#customerTable').append(datea);
});

function test(id) {

var data = '{"id":"' + id+ '"}'; 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to this id that is integer send to server that i cant . 'function test(idd) {
    alert(idd);
   
    var dataa = { "id": idd }
    alert(dataa);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/api/Values/',
        data: JSON.stringify(dataa),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (results) {
            $.getJSON("api/Values", LoadData);
            alert('Customer Deleted!');
        }

    })

}'

Comment: If the item.id is an integer you can remove the ' chars.:
<input type="button" name="btnDelete" id="' + item.id + '" onClick="test(' + item.id  + ')"  value="Delete" /></td>'.

Or you can use  parseInt(item.id). Check this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp .Sorry bad english, hope it helps.

Comment: TNX @Juan but when pressed button show this error :Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51605/api/Values/'."
MessageDetail: "No action was found on the controller 'Values' that matches the request."

Comment: I think you have a backend/json problem now. As i see you are stringifing a string. You have : data = '{....}'. Send the data whitout stringify:
data: dataa;

Comment: Since i cant comment in your answer because mi low reputation I will try my best. Check data.id is a integer, if not, use parseInt(data.id). Whats technologies are you using? Sory bad english.

Comment: id is string but dont matter im checking integer id ,it have a error yet.web api mvc4...tnx again

Answer (score 0):

CONTROLLER:

```
 public void Delete(int id)
    {
        using (DataClasses1DataContext db=new DataClasses1DataContext())
        {
            var q = from item in db.usepas
                    where item.id == id
                    select item;
            usepa s = q.FirstOrDefault();
            db.usepas.DeleteOnSubmit(s);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

Ajax Code :

```
function test(id) {
alert(id);

var data = { id: id }

alert(data.id);
$.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    url: '/api/Values',
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (results) {
        $.getJSON('api/Values', LoadData);
        alert('Customer Deleted!');
    }

})
```

}

Comment: @Juan tnx again for helping me :)